# Showing set inclusion for sigma algebra generated by function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I want to show the equivalence of two sigma algebras, namely the sigma algebra generated by a function $f:\Sigma\to\mathbb{\bar R}$ and $\cap\mathcal{F}\space$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra of sets of $\Sigma$ and $f$ is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{\bar B})$-measurable. $\sigma(f):=\{f^{-1}(B)|B\in\mathcal{\bar B}\}$, so in showing this equivalence, showing $\cap\mathcal{F}\subset\sigma(f)$ seems straightforward. However, I ran into trouble trying to prove the inclusion in the other direction.
Assuming that $X\in\sigma(f)$, this means that $X\in\{f^{-1}(B)|B\in\mathcal{\bar B}\}$. What does this tell me in order to arrive at the desired result? I can see why it must be part of one of the $\mathcal{F}$'s that are part of the intersection, but what tells me that it is actually part of the intersection itself? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that $\sigma (f) $ is a sigma algebra and that $f$ is measurable w.r.t. this sigma algebra. Hence $\cap\mathcal F$ is contained in this.

Intersection of a family of sets is always contained in any member of the family. Here $\sigma(f)$ is itself a member of the family.

Converse part: If $\mathcal F$ is any sigma algebra w.r.t. which $f$ is measurable then $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal F$ for every Borel set $B$ by definition of measurability. Hence $\sigma (f) \subset \mathcal F$. This is true for each $\mathcal F$ so $\sigma (f)$ is contained in the intersection of all that $\mathcal F$'s.

Comment: @user569579 Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just deleted my comment because I realised the set inclusion in my problem statement was the wrong way around (I have now edited it). I had already shown the direction that you just helped me with, albeit in a slightly different way. This was the direction that seemed rather trivial. It's the other inclusion I struggle with.

Comment: @user569579 See  my answer now.

Comment: Thank you for you updating your answer, much appreciated. I am surprised that the answer was so simple.